# How to rename model generated from ADO.NET Entity Model scaffold

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm creating a database first web api and using ADO.NET entity model to generate my model and DBContext. I'm not trying to create the models off of any tables in the database, but instead, off of stored procedures.

When I generate the .edmx file the model is automatically assigned *name of stored procedure*_Result.cs

I want to be able to rename this so when I return JSON of these objects they aren't all *name of stored procedure*_Result

Comment: You can rename these 'entities' by opening up the .edmx file and modifying the Entity's name.

Comment: Just rename the Complex Type created by the Function Import.